# Загрузка Debian

Tags: debian

Обновили ядро линукс, перестал грузиться debian. Что можно чекнуть через rescue режим?

syslog:

```
Apr 26 09:45:56 server systemd-modules-load[332]: Failed to insert 'ipmi_si': No such device
Apr 26 09:45:56 server systemd-modules-load[332]: Inserted module 'ipmi_watchdog'
Apr 26 09:45:56 server systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 26 09:45:56 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
Apr 26 09:45:56 server systemd[1]: Unit systemd-modules-load.service entered failed state
```

Comment: под фразу "престал грузиться" подходит слишком много. Нужны уточнения - не находи ядро или загружает его, но падает с стектрейсом и тому подобное.

Comment: syslog

    Apr 26 09:45:56 server systemd-modules-load[332]: Failed to insert 'ipmi_si': No such device  
    Apr 26 09:45:56 server systemd-modules-load[332]: Inserted module 'ipmi_watchdog'  
    Apr 26 09:45:56 server systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE  
    Apr 26 09:45:56 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.  
    Apr 26 09:45:56 server systemd[1]: Unit systemd-modules-load.service entered failed state.

Comment: а зачем rescue? загрузите работоспособную версию программы *linux*. а потом соберите требующуюся вам версию уже с поддержкой *ipmi_si*. или «уговорите» systemd не грузить несуществующий модуль. или (в идеале) вообще выкиньте этот systemd туда, где ему самое место.

Comment: в данный момент на сервер можно зайти только через него, это может быть причиной не загрузки?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin решение вида "выкинуть systemd", по сути, означает "уйти с дебиана на кастомную сборку". При всех плюсах такого решения для знающего что он делает профи и бы не назвал его идеалом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это не «кастомная сборка». это просто удаление ряда пакетов. никаких сборок/разборок/кастомизаций/и т.п. для совсем «неграмотных» даже инструкцию написали по поводу jessie (где systemd стоит по умолчанию): http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_remove_systemd_from_a_Debian_jessie/sid_installation